# What's the difference between $p(x \mid \theta)$ and $p(x; \theta)$?

Tags: probability, density-function, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meaning of probability notations $P(z;d,w)$ and $P(z|d,w)$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10234/meaning-of-probability-notations-pzd-w-and-pzd-w)

Can you tell me the difference between $p(x \mid \theta)$  and  $p(x; \theta)$? 
I know $p(x \mid \theta)$ is the conditional pdf, then what about  $p(x; \theta)$?